# SQL запрос по непустым $_GET параметрам?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть некая форма, после ее заполнения передается четыре `$GET` параметра. Исходя из того что я получил, мне нужно передать эти параметры в SQL запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table p WHERE t.t1 = '$get1' AND t.t2 = '$get2' AND t.t3 = '$get3' AND t.t4 = '$get4'
```

Проблема в том, что не все 4 поля могут быть использованы, то есть человек мог выбрать только 2 поля - остальные не выбрал и они оказались пустыми. Но тогда запрос ничего не возвращает. Писать кучу условий `if` - не вариант (если, конечно, он не единственный). Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое: **никогда нельзя опрокидывать напрямую пришедшие данные в базу**.

Второе: можно просто отфильтровать `$_GET`, что убьет пустые значения:

```
$data = array_filter(array_map('trim', $_GET));
```

Еще лучше - если в `$_GET` завести специальный ключ под это дело

```
$rawData = isset($_GET['data']) ? $_GET['data'] : [];
$data = array_filter(array_map('trim', $rawData));
// дальше решается, нужна ли вообще обработка, если $data оказался пустым
```

После этого начинаются пляски с бубнами. Полученные данные надо безопасно передать в БД, и для этого необходимо немного напрячь PDO.

```
$conditionChunks = [];
$chunkFormat = 't.t%d = :param_%s';
$i = 1;
foreach (array_keys($data) as $id => $key) {
    $conditionChunks[] = sprintf($chunkFormat, $id + 1, $key);
}
// в этот момент мы получаем строчку формата ' WHERE t.t1 = :param_smth AND t.t2 = :param_anthr_smth'
$condition = $conditionChunks ? ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditionChunks) : '';
// Теперь необходимо собрать сам запрос
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table p' . $condition;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
// подставляем значения
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $statement->bindValue(':param_' . $key, $value);
}
// и, наконец, его можно выполнять
$statement->execute();
$data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

входящие параметры можно проверять на значение `NULL`.
тоесть запрос может выглядеть примерно так так.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table p 
 WHERE (t.t1 = '$get1' OR $get1 is null) 
   AND (t.t2 = '$get2' OR $get2 is null)
   AND (t.t3 = '$get3' OR $get3 is null) 
   AND (t.t4 = '$get4' OR $get4 is null);
```